# Why is my PhoneGap app w/ Facebook ignoring all clicks?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cordova, ios-simulator

I have a PhoneGap app in which I've just added the Facebook iOS SDK, however when running the iPhone simulator, all clicks are ignored (ie. when I click anything, nothing happens). When I click the home button, I can see the button being pressed in, but nothing happens (my app isn't minimized).

I just upgraded to Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6. I followed the [PhoneGap Facebook guide](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect), but it seems I've done something very wrong and I have no idea what it is - I'm getting no errors. The only output I get is:

```
2012-10-14 17:11:45.529 MyAppName[18019:19a03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
```

Has anyone ever run into this problem or know what could be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be an Xcode bug after upgrading. I restarted it and the simulator worked again.